# Operator norm of a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Consider the operator on $L^2(\Bbb R)$, $f\rightarrow f*g$, where $g\geq 0$ is some $L^1$ function. Show the operator is a bounded linear operator with operator norm equal to $||g||_1$.

Showing this actually is a linear operator was not hard, and the operator norm is less than $||g||_1$ by Young's inequality, but I have had no luck trying to show the operator norm is actually $||g||_1$.

Comment: You could use an approximation to the identity.

Comment: @julien How do I guarantee convergence in $L^p$ with some approximation? I know how I can guarantee convergence point wise almost everywhere, but that's it.

Comment: look on the fourier transform side

Comment: @mike I don't see any approach related to the fourier transform...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question [Limit of convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665753/limit-of-convolution) answers the question for general convolution operator on $L^p$.