# For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $f,g$ such that $\|f\ast g\|_p>(1-\epsilon)\|f\|_1\|g\|_p$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, for $1\leq p\leq\infty$. A well-known is result, called [Young's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions) is that
$$\|f\ast g\|_p\leq\|f\|_1\|g\|_p,$$
where
$$(f\ast g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-y)g(y)\,dy$$
is the convolution of $f$ and $g$. Now, the problem that I want to solve is to show we can "get close" to equality in the following precise sense:

> For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that
>   $$\|f\ast g\|_p>(1-\epsilon)\|f\|_1\|g\|_p.$$

I am having a hard time trying to get functions satisfying this. Do you have any idea of how to approach this?

Comment: You want $f$ to be an approximation of the identity. Try $f(x) = M$ for $0 < x < M^{-1}$, $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This question [Limit of convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665753/limit-of-convolution) should give a solution to your problem. In your notation, consider the sequence $g_n= (2n)^{-1/p} \chi_{(-n,n)}$ and $f$ is any positive integrable function.