# Operator norm of convolution operator in L1

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, convolution

I have a convolution operator $T$ in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ defined as $T:f \rightarrow f*g$ , for some $g \in L^1(R)$. 
I need to prove that $||T||_{L^1}=||g||_{L^1}$. 
I have found such problem here: [Limit of convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665753/limit-of-convolution) and i've tried to solve mine in a similar way, but i have some trouble with it.
As i understand it, this solution uses the fact, that $g$ is non-negative to approximate an integral.
 Here is what @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla states:
"Namely, if $\epsilon>0$, then $\exists n_\varepsilon\in{\Bbb N}
$ s.t. for $x\in[-n_\varepsilon,n_\varepsilon]$: $\|g\|_1-\epsilon/2\le\int_{-n_\epsilon}^{n_\epsilon}g"
$ 
I understand how we can do this for positive function and i assume that a similar approach can be used for negative functions. But when $Im(g) \in R$ such approximation can't be done, if I'm not mistaken.  It seems to me that in such case it still can be showed that $||f*g||_{L^1}\geq||g||_{L^1}-\epsilon$. I've tried to represent $g$ as difference of two positive functions i.e. $g^+$ and $g^-$ such that $g=g^+-g^-$, but when I try to estimate $||f*(g^+-g^-)||_{L^1}$,  i can't come up with a desired inequality.
Would be very glad for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to worry about these decompositions. A standard mollification argument can be used here.

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a smooth, compactly supported function such that $\int\varphi=1$. For $\epsilon>0$ define
$$
\varphi_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}\epsilon\varphi(x/\epsilon).
$$
Note that $\int\varphi_\epsilon=1$ and we have
\begin{align*}
|T\varphi_\epsilon(x)-f(x)|&=|\int (f(x-y)-f(x))\varphi_\epsilon(y)\,dy|\le \int |f(x-y)-f(x)|\varphi_\epsilon(y)\,dy\\
&=\int |f(x-\epsilon y)-f(x)|\varphi(y)\,dy.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\|T\varphi_\epsilon-f\|_{L^1}&\le \int \|f(\cdot-\epsilon y)-f(\cdot)\|_{L^1}\varphi(y)\,dy\longrightarrow 0, \quad\textrm{as}\quad\epsilon\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
In particular it implies
\begin{align*}
\|T\|\ge \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\|T\varphi_\epsilon\|_{L^1}=\|f\|_{L^1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just a couple of questions here:
What means compactly supported function?
Am i right, that there is a typo and $\epsilon$>0?
Did you forget about the modulus in the first integral?
And i don't understand why $||T||_{L^1} \geq limit$, why is it implied?

Comment: 1) it should be $\epsilon>0$ and I forgot about a modulus, I corrected it. Thanks. 2) Observe that $\|T\|=\sup_{\|g\|_{L^1}=1} \|Tg\|_{L^1}$ so in particular $\|T\|\ge \sup_{\epsilon}\|T\varphi_\epsilon\|_{L^1}$, since all $\varphi_\epsilon$ have $L^1$-norm $1$, and $\sup$ is always greater than a limit.

Comment: All right, now i get it. And the last question about compactly supported function. Am i right that this means, that function is non-zero only on some compact?

Comment: And one question about that inequality for norm. Why is it less than integral? Am i right, that we used Fubini's theorem for it?

Comment: A function is compactly supported if it's zero outside a compact set (compact means essentially closed and bounded; you can think that it is zero outside the interval $(0,1)$).  As to inequality involving a norm, it is moving the absolute value inside the integral and then applying Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: Now i understand everything. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome :]